# Visual Studio Chart tool in blank app

Tags: c#, charts, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to add a chart tool in my C# Windows 8.1 blank app in Visual Studio 2015 but the chart tool is greyed out. I made sure that I'm using .NET Framework above 4 (currently set to 4.6) but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried resetting the tool box as suggested by other posts.

I also noticed that the chart tool is only available through the Windows Form Application but I'm not sure how to transition my Blank App project to a Forms App. I tried however the Forms App will not let me add a reference I need (WindowsPreview.Kinect) for the app.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone else is looking for a solution, I found a post that goes through adding charts to a Windows 8 App (Once you open the example project it will give you an option to update to 8.1 if you want).

http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2013/03/06/charting-in-windows-8-store-apps.aspx

I also recommend installing the Windows 8.1 version of the WinRTXaml Took Kit if you will be using Windows 8.1 by typing the below line to the Package manager console

```
PM> Install-Package WinRTXamlToolkit.Windows
```